# making seaborn heatmap from DataFrame plot to be aware of data ranges

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, heatmap

How can one make seaborn heatmap (created from a pandas DataFrame plot) to be aware of the data ranges? I.e. when I hover the mouse pointer over the plot, I can see in the bottom right corner of the plot window **"x= y="**, while I want to see coordinates of the point on the plot I am hovering over (for example, **"x=25.6, y=3.3"**), assuming, of course, that the input DataFrame contains a 2D histogram with equal size bins along each axis.

Alternatively, maybe I could create such plot in a different way to achieve the same effect? For example, with `ax.hist2d` I get it out of the box, but I want to be able to compute with custom code content of each bin and make it effectively a heatmap plot (with color coding of the bin contents).

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Index = [ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0]
Cols  = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0]
df = pd.DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(5, 5)), 
    index=Index, columns=Cols)
plt.close(1)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(num=1)
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True)
plt.show(block=False)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `sns.heatmap(...)` by `ax.imshow(..)`, you're close to what you need.  You can then set the extent of the image to the data range you need.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Index = [ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0]
Cols  = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0]
df = pd.DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(5, 5)), 
    index=Index, columns=Cols)
plt.close(1)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(num=1)
dx = np.diff(df.columns)[0]/2
dy = np.diff(df.index)[0]/2
extent = [df.columns.min()-dx, df.columns.max()+dx,
          df.index.min()-dy, df.index.max()+dy] 
ax.imshow(df, extent=extent, aspect="auto")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedFormatter


class CustomFormatter(FixedFormatter):
    def __init__(self, old):
        super().__init__(old.seq)

    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        return self.seq[abs(self.locs - x).argmin()]

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(CustomFormatter(plt.gca().xaxis.get_major_formatter()))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(CustomFormatter(plt.gca().yaxis.get_major_formatter()))
```